# Is there an acceptable way to promote a new Area 51 topic in questions that use a certain tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a topic which I feel deserves its own StackExchange site.  Currently, there is no one dominant forum for enthusiasts in this area to contribute.  There is a Google Group which gets a question or two a day and there is a StackOverflow tag which also gets questions at about the same rate.  I feel the sum would be much greater than its parts...

Is there an acceptable way for me to promote the new Area 51 topic in StackOverflow questions that use this tag?

Comment: Two questions a day across two sites isn't going to make for a very successful Area 51 proposal...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this has been discussed before, but I don't think there's a good way to do this in questions. Any comments on a question should be geared towards clarifying/refining the question itself. Promoting another site, even another Stack Exchange site, and *especially* a site that doesn't even exist yet, doesn't really do that.

---

What you *can* do is look for people who are active in your tag and check their profile for contact information. If they've posted a Twitter handle, for example, that's tacit permission to contact them. Reach out to them and see if they'd be interested in following or committing to an Area 51 proposal.

Answer (score 2):

If there are questions that are satisfactorily handled on Stack Overflow, then why would you want a different site? Think about it from the readers' perspective: “hey, SO is nice, and there's also this hypothetical place where your question would fit”. Yeah, whatever.

The one circumstance I can think where it would be both smart and appropriate to advertise a different site is if a question is closed as off-topic. Then it is appropriate to mention another venue where the question could be asked, and this brings attention to your proposal to someone who needs it.

If there's a chatroom dedicated to that tag or a related topic, you can advertise the proposal there. Once, not repeatedly!

Comment: Because sometimes the scope of StackOverflow only covers a subset of the topic. For example, Stackoverflow has questions on OpenCart, but only the things directly related to OpenCart "programming" is allowed on Stackoverflow. The truth is that anyone who does OpenCart programming/development is also an OpenCart admin,  yet not all questions regarding OpenCart administration is allowed on StackOverflow. That's why a new site for OpenCart exists on area51 http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart . It's the same with wordpress SE.